# External .resx files during runtime

Tags: wpf, localization, resx

What options do i have, if i want to localize WPF applications. I would like to have option to fill .resx files for languages, and that works. But I need to get language during runtime from files.

So my question is: Is it possible to get external .resx in WPF apps. And change language during runtime? Or am I looking at this issue at bad angle?

Comment: I am looking for the same functionality, did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just compile your resx files along with your default resources?

Set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to your desired culture, then call [ResourceManager.GetString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk.aspx) to set your localized properties.

If you wanted to get another culture, use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsb0cfet.aspx). Something like:

```
    public static string GetStringForCurrentUICulture(string name)
    {
        var value = _resourceManager.GetString(name, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
        return value;
    }
```

To add a resource dynamically, use the appropriate ResourceManager [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx), which allows you to specify the resource and the assembly it is contained within.

Comment: Yea i do this thing right now, but i want to know if it is possible, to get these files without building into app. It's like i have 3 languages inside app and i want to add new language to an app, i need to build this app again, and use it. But i want to know is it possible to just add resx (or other kind) of file into app directory, and attach this language to existing languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can Localize the  wpf application using the [LocBaml Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
This helps to create the resx files and make mapping to xaml

Comment: Yea i read about this tool, but i would like to know, if i'm able to create resx files, just add them to directory and use them without building to app (without compiling)

Comment: @IgorisAzanovas I am looking for the same functionality, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @faldeland In the end i made localization wrapper which used Database and if it could not find there it would try accessing from resources. I could not find better solution at that moment.